# Handling different soap actions in spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, soap-client

I have a spring integration application (outbound soap gateway). It calls a 3rd party `SOAP` web service which exposes multiple SOAP actions. How can I specify SOAP action dynamically or map it to different API call in the Spring gateway so that I don't have to rewrite channels/spring integration logic for every action.

I have search for examples and have a hunch that manipulating `header-enricher` might be useful here. But I am unable to find a specific example for it or if it is the right thing to do.

My environment is `Java6`, `Spring Integration 4.2.0`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest your explanation isn't clear at a glance.

Since you mention `SOAP_ACTION` and `header-enricher`, I only can suggest something like this:

```
<header-enricher input-channel="expressionInput">
    <soap-action expression="@soapActionProvider.getSoapAction(payload)"/>
</header-enricher>
```

where `soapActionProvider` is some bean which is responsible to return an appropriate value for the `SOAP_ACTION` header according to the accepted `payload` of request message.

The logic may be any complexity there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question. All I want is to call multiple soap actions from an outbound gateway using the same integration chain. In your solution, how can i know which gateway method was called (as every gateway method will correspond to different soap action).

Comment: ??? Which gateway methods? The `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` just implements `MessageHandler` and deals with something like XML in the SOAP style from the `payload`. Your new info makes me more blind. Please, share the configuration on the matter and point me out  what you don't like there.